# Что поменять чтобы ajax подгрузка работала от скроллинга?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код ajax подгрузки, работающий от нажатия на ссылку. Что поменять, чтобы подгружалось при достижении конца блока div? То есть, как правильно прописать условие?

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-js-showmore-products="1"]', function(e){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('?') == -1){
              url = url + '?m=1';
            } else {
              url = url + '&m=1';
            }
            catalogFilter.updateFilters({
              'url': url
            });
            e.preventDefault();
          });
```

Comment: тут не условие нужно, а отслеживание когда конец блока попадает в видимую зону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**scroll()** - Устанавливает обработчик "прокрутки" элементов документа.

**offset()** - Возвращает/устанавливает координаты относительно начала страницы

**scrollTop()** - Получает / устанавливает значение отступа прокрутки сверху

**height()** - Функции возвращают высоту элемента.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var block = $('.without__line');
    var div = block.offset(); 
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scroll >= div.top + block.height()-400){
        var url = $(block).find('[data-js-more-buttons="1"]').parent().find('[‌​data-js-showmore-pro‌​ducts="1"]')[0].href
        if (url.indexOf('?') == -1){
            url = url + '?m=1';
        } else {
            url = url + '&m=1';
        }
        catalogFilter.updateFilters({
            'url': url
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
});
```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" Не нравится эта строчка
if (url.indexOf('?') == -1){

Comment: Потому и спрашиваю, что перепробовав варианты, натыкался на ошибки. И не понимаю, как исправить

Comment: <a data-js-showmore-products="1" class="b-link btn-gray" href="/catalog/smesiteli/?offset=20" title=""></a>

Comment: https://ibb.co/hkE28G

Comment: Сделал. Можете смотреть.

Comment: Да, кнопку можно полностью убрать

Comment: Генерируется автоматически фреймворком

Comment: Как называется библиотека или есть ли возможность подредактировать скрип который генерирует кнопку, как вы выводите ее именно в этом месте? Есть ли возможность добавить ID или CLASS к данной кнопки?

Comment: В данном случае вы можете сделать так: var  url = $(block).find('[data-js-more-buttons="1"]').parent().find('[data-js-showmore-products="1"]')[0].href   Обратите внимание на класс указанный в block. 
    var block = $('.without__line');

Comment: Заработало. Но загрузка происходит, когда прокручиваю почти до момента, когда кнопку уже не видно

Comment: Куда поблагодарить?

Comment: if(scroll >= div.top + block.height()-400) Вместо 400 укажите нужную высоту, чем больше значение тем выше будет срабатывать код.

Comment: Поблагодарить можете нажав на кнопку правильного ответа.  Это не самое верное решение для этого действия.  Так придется скрыть кнопки средствами CSS.

Comment: Хорошо. Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: Вы можете попробовать сделать вот так: <script> var url = {{ Yii.app().... тут напишите код с атрибута href }}</script> В том файле где выводятся кнопки.  Но не знаю сработает ли в вашем случае. А в коде common.js удалить ту переменную url.   Это будет чуть лучше чем такое решение.